# Fetch single row from SQL DB using Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, pdf, datatable, crystal-reports

I have run into a problem where my crystal report is creating pdf pages of every record, despite the datatable being parsed into the pdf generation only containing one row.

There is a query I have which selects a single row based on an Id, is then put into a dataset datatable and parsed into the crystal report generation.

Stepping through I can confirm that the datatable contains only one row, yet the output is multiple pages of the pdf, each display a different row.

Has anyone come across this before, if so, what's causing my datatable to be ingored?

**Code behind:**

```
public string CreateMaster(int Id)
        {
            DataTable dt = DataGrabber(Id);// returns a dataset
            ExportOptions expo = new ExportOptions();
            PdfRtfWordFormatOptions form = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
            string op = "";
            string smp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
            DiskFileDestinationOptions dfd = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
            op = @"E:\SomeFolder\Client_ID" + Id + "_TS"+ smp + ".pdf";

            using (ClientDdPdf pdf = new ClientDdPdf())
            {
                pdf.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Portrait;
                pdf.PrintOptions.PaperSize = PaperSize.PaperA4;
                pdf.SetDatabaseLogon(DbUser,DbPass,DbServer,DbDb);
                pdf.SetDataSource(dt); // confirmed that the single datatable from dataset is parsed
                dfd.DiskFileName = op;
                expo = pdf.ExportOptions;
                expo.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                expo.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                expo.DestinationOptions = dfd;
                expo.ExportFormatOptions = form;
                pdf.Export(expo);
            }
            ReadPdfFile(op);
            return op;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why this was the problem, but it didn't like the custom query I was parsing when there already was a query in crystal reports.

The solution found for this was to map the crystal report to a view. Essentially this was still taking the same fields from the same tables but it did take the parsed in datatable and churn out the desired field.

To clarify, I didn't change my code at all, I was still using the same query in order to get the necessary datatable, but when binding the crystal report to a database, I didn't bind it to the tables, but to a view I created instead.